# Dynamic tag name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert a dynamic tag naming system from React into a more **hook** like approach, what I'm doing is first I import and export a few components so that I can pull them all at once on a array, like this:

```
import Component1 from './Component1/Component1'
import Component2 from './Component2/Component2'

 export {
     Component1,
     Component2
 }
```

And then I load them like so:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import * as Components from './../AllComponents/Components'

function importHook() {

  const [states, setStates] = useState({
    components: [],
    currentComponent: 0
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    Object.entries(Components).forEach(component => {
      setStates(prevState => ({ components: [...prevState.components, component[1]]}))
   })
  }, []) // Look's into Components and adds every component to the 'components' array so that I can use that array in the next step.

  return states;
}

export default importHook
```

And after that I proceed to do so:

```
import React from 'react'
import './MainComponent.scss'
import importHook from '../../importHook'

function MainComponent() {

    const { components, currentComponent } = importHook() // Pull and set the values using the hook 

    const TagName = components[currentComponent] // Created the tag name by targeting the first function, seeing as currentComponent should be 0 at the time

    console.log('Tag:  ' + TagName) // undefined

    return (
        <div className="h-100">
            <TagName /> // crashes everything
        </div>
    )

}

export default MainComponent
```

So I have figured out that the reason that `<TagName />` crashes everything is because something runs twice.

If you remove `<TagName />` so that you can get the output from `console.log` and change `currentComponent` inside the `const TagName` to `0`, you notice that the first time `console.log` runs is returns `undefined`, while the second run returns the actual function that is stored inside the array.

So really my question is just, why / what executes twice? I have an idea, I'm assuming its because of the `forEach` that's adding to the array or something like that, but I'm not completely sure.

What can be done so that we can have all the values ready before returning here? I haven't tried this yet, but I assume I could introduce a `if statement` that would check and see if the variable is empty and if so, display some kind of loading screen or fidget, but this doesn't seem like the best solution to me, I know there are a lot of ways to do something but not all are good and since I'm really new to all of this its better to read / ask.

About the read part, couldn't find much about solving this or the implementation that I've mentioned, I have tried useEffect, useCallback and other such, not sure if I've been doing it wrong though...

Comment: are you aware that, useEffect will be called multiple times? And the logic inside swipeDetection is also important. You shouldn't have any conditions to call your importHook. 
Moreover, what's the point to merge all components together? You can create one custom hook "useTagName()" which would hold a state in a global level variable

Comment: Sorry the swipeDetection thing was the old name, forgot to change it up, I've minimized everything here so that it would be easier to understand. I am kind of aware about the useEffect thing, I mean, I said I'm assuming that's what's causing the re-run / render. Thank's for this idea though, you're pretty right I guess, I could just give up on trying to import the components and number in here and just leaving and modify everything in there, but my idea is that, you have all the functions in the array, so with a swipe detected, any time you want to see some other component, all you need to do

Comment: is swipe left or right to `-1` / `+1` to number and so change the function that is being passed inside the `const TagName` and so change the component that is being displayed. So it can be quite handy if you see where I'm getting at. This is also the reason I'm pulling all the functions inside the array.

Comment: The lifecycle is as follows: MainComponent starts, importHook creates the state with 0 components, Main component renders, TagName crashes here, assuming there wouldn't be any TagName it would continue as: useEffect is called from import hook, after first render of MainComponent (think of it as componentDidMounted here). What happens when you conditionally render TagName ?

Comment: I've just tried to conditionally render it now, doesn't seem to work like this either for some reason, I've done this `return ( <div> { typeof TagName === underfined ? ( <div> Test Loading div...</div> ) : ( <div> <TagName /> </div> ) } </div> ) and it returns `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function` ... I'm a bit stooped I gotta admit :D but I think I understand the cycle very well now from you explanation, it makes sens too because the MainComponent has to call the impotHook, but I thought it wouldn't try to render `<TagName>`

Comment: better add "if !Tagname return null", before the actual return value

Comment: before everything in the `importHook` would be finished and `importHook` would finish updating everything inside the MainComponent

Comment: useEffect = componentDidUpdate, componentDidMount. If you have this mindset, it'd be easier to understand lifecycle of hooks. Btw, just realised, in your importHook, Components is a static data. Why do you even bother to use hooks over it? Just create currentComponent state in your MainComponent

Comment: well, this is going to be something that exists in a few different components and I don't want to have to create the states and update them in each component, I want everything to happen in the hook, all the components to be pulled in the array, once, there

Comment: adding `typeof TagName == 'function'` to `render` fixes the issue and components render, I don't like this solution but, following the the life-cycle explanation, it sounds like there might not be a cleaner way of fixing this. I will move all of the logic into the hook and just push the TagName to the component, that sounds like a better and cleaner solution, less DRY code. Also I'll continue to try to find something better to do with this, just for future reference.

I'll wait till Monday and if something better doesn't show you can post the answer for me to accept @DoğancanArabacı, Thanks!